# Добрый день, возникла проблема на с++. Мне необходимо создать структуру, внутри объединение, а потом проинициализировать элементы из объединения

Tags: c++, struct, union

возникла проблема с заданием на с++. Мне необходимо создать структуру, внутри объединение, а потом проинициализировать элементы из объединения. Буду рад помощи!

```
struct stack {
    string name_of_goods;
    union quality{
        int number_of_goods;
        double value_of_goods;
        string date;
    };
}arr[5];
```

После указанного участка кода с клавиатуры ввести значения по количеству товара, его стоимости, дате, имени.

Comment: Вы уверены что для товара, нужно хранить или количество, или цену, или дату, как это храниться у вас сейчас? Возможно union нужно было применить для чего-то другого?

Comment: Создать тип структуры согласно варианту, организовать поля этой структуры 
так, чтобы они содержали объединение, перечисление (можно добавить 
дополнительные поля) и битовое поле.

Comment: Это дословное условие

Comment: Вам в первую очередь нужно четко представлять что такое объединение, как с ним работать. Во вторых тип  string имеет нетривиальный конструктор ,  потому не может быть членом объединения.

Comment: Спасибо большое! И правда над структурами надо посидеть подольше.

Comment: Можно храить число штук (int) - для штучных товаров и вес (double) - для весовых.